# is there a way to getObjects from s3 with the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I Want to get my image from s3 but using the URL as a parameter in the params is that possible. Currently, I am getting my images using the key.

```
    const downloadParams = {
        Key: fileKey,
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME
    };

    const data = await s3.getObject(downloadParams);
    const stream = await fs.createReadStream(data);

    return await s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream();
}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about your situation. Why do you want to use the URL instead of the Key? Are the objects in buckets in your own AWS Account? Are the objects publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full image URL you can use `request` or a similar library to get the file instead of using `s3.getObject`